# Add spaces at cursor position

Tags: regex, vim, space, text-cursor

I would like to know if it is possible to add spaces (30 spaces) at cursor position

I tried to do it with regex but I don't know how to represent the actual cursor position in regex.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd> will add 30 spaces at the cursor position in command mode.

Comment: They are actually added when you getting out of insert mode (using ESC for example)

Comment: ...and if you do this often you can add `:nmap <F2> 30i<Space><Esc>` to your `.vimrc` file and just press the `<F2>` key in normal mode.

Comment: thank you :) Just one thing.. I noted that the spaces are inserted before the cursor. What would be the code if the spaces are inserted after the cursor (the cursor remains at the same place)

Comment: @Remonn: No, the spaces are not inserted before the cursor. They are inserted in the cursor position as you've asked. I see many people getting confused with this. When the cursor is a block (normal mode) it is easy. If you have it positioned in the 32nd character and hit `i`, the new characters will inserted in the 32nd position. Makes sense? Now, if you want to insert after the cursor you need to "append" so use `a` instead of `i`. And remember, when the cursor is a thin bar (insert mode) it is not sitting between two characters –the cursor never does that– you're just seeing its left part.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use vim register for this:

"a defines register a and if you cut a whitespace with "ax makes register a has whitespace. Then use:

`30"ap`

2. Cut a whitespace with x and paste it with 30p

Note: Registers don't forget its value so first solution is more useful.

Comment: Always good to show that there are many ways to do the same thing, so +1, even though I think khachick's answer is the way I would do it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to already given answers I can say that cursor position is represented in regex with `\%#`, so `s/\%#/\=repeat(" ", 30)/` will add 30 spaces at cursor position just like `30i<Space><Esc>`.

Comment: Thank you ZyX. The cursors moves to the beginning of the line. Is it possible to keep the cursor at the same place (place the spaces after the cursor)?

Comment: @Remonn `30a<Space><Esc>` or `s/\%(\%#\%(.\|$\)\)\@<=/\=repeat(" ", 30)/`. If you don't want to move cursor you will have to surround each of the commands with `let winview=winsaveview() | ... | call winrestview(winview)`.